# How to make dynamic table using android xml?

Tags: android, xml, tablelayout

Guys i have a `XML` file containing `TableLayout` as follows:

```
    <ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/resulttable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3" >

 </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is another layout named row.xml as follows

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/tr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tv_discription"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tv_left_vehicle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tv_right_vehicle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </TableRow>
```

In the above table i want to show array list of string, for this i have done following code:

```
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.resulttable);
        for(int i=0;i<DArray.size();i++)
        {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
            TableRow row = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, table, false);

            String discription = DArray.get(i);
            String leftVehicle = LArray.get(i);
            String rightVehicle = RArray.get(i);

            TextView tvD = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_discription);
            tvD.setText(discription);
            TextView tvlPrice = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_left_vehicle);
            tvlPrice.setText(leftVehicle);
            TextView tvrPrice = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_right_vehicle);
            tvrPrice.setText(rightVehicle);

            row.addView(tvD);
            row.addView(tvlPrice);
            row.addView(tvrPrice);
            table.addView(row);
        }
```

but this code is arising exception. Here is LogCat error for my code.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1897): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

I am beginner for this situation please help me find out the problem.

for more detail i want to make a table like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to create table Pragmatically or via xml??

Comment: i want to make it via xml

Comment: Why Cant you use listview and custom adapters for this implementation?. which will make your life easier.

Comment: i have add screenshot, which gives me sample of what i want please tell me how to do like like that

Answer (score 0):

Okay the second potential problem is also: table.addView(row);

rowgets added every single loop iteration but it's the same view. You can only add a view once to the hierarchy. You probably want a new instance for each loop iteration. I can't say for sure but this is likely the problem. or try to add with index position in viewgroup like table.addView(row, index);